# Get Apache2.2 to hide Microsoft documents that are being edited?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf, regex, regular-expressions

I have a htdocs directory where I am serving a few Microsoft Word documents.  When someone is editing a document, the name of the document changes to look like something like this:  "**~$my_document.doc**"  and also **.tmp** files are created that represent edits of the document until the document is closed.

So, I want Apache to not serve these files until the user is finished editing them.  So, I want to hide files ending with **.tmp**  extension at the same time that I am hiding files that start with "**~$**" .

So, can anyone help me enhance this Apache directive to accomplish this?

```
<Directory "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs">
    <Files ~ "\.tmp$">
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
    </Files>
.....
</Directory>
```

This is a regular expression trick that is beyond my ability right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a system to test, but I would suppose you need to do something like this.

This should match either any file name that starts with a `~$` followed by anything, and any files that end in `.tmp`.

```
<FilesMatch "(~\$.*|\.tmp)$"> ... </FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do another `<Files>` block with the expression `^~\$`.

Keep in mind that the original file doesn't disappear when the file's being edited - if that's a problem for what you're looking to do, then you'll need some more complex regex voodoo.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I should have thought of that.